# Need to check date time and adding a class to my div

Tags: php

```
 foreach($this->connection->query($sql) as $row) {

                     $class = "";
                     if($row['datum'] > date("Y-m-d") && $row['tijd'] > date("H:i:s")) { $class = "toekomst"; }
                     if($row['datum'] == date("Y-m-d") && $row['tijd'] == date("H:i:s")) { $class = "vandaag"; }
                     if($row['datum'] < date("Y-m-d") && $row['tijd'] < date("H:i:s")) { $class = "verleden"; }

                     var_dump($class);
                     $output .= "<tr class='$class'>";
                          $output .= "<td>";
                               //Rotate date from sql to dutch notation
                               $datum   = $row['datum'];
                               $dag     = substr($datum, 8, 2);
                               $maand   = substr($datum, 5, 2);
                               $jaar    = substr($datum, 0, 4);
                               $datum   = $dag . "-" . $maand . "-" . $jaar;

                               $output .= $datum;
```

i think i almost got it but still not working perfect if i dump the class its giving me

```
string(0) "" string(8) "verleden" string(0) "" string(0) "" string(0) "" string(0) "" string(0) "" string(0) "" string(0) "" string(0) "" string(8) "verleden" string(0) "" string(0) "" string(8) "toekomst" string(8) "toekomst"
```

Comment: Sounds like instead of `if($row['datum'] == date("Y-m-d H:i:s"))` you need something like `if($row['datum'] == date("Y-m-d") && $row['tijd'] == date("H:i:s"))`

Comment: Why would you have two different columns for this? Just have one datetime column.

Comment: I think i allmost got it @Amunium they are all white now with no class any tips ?

Comment: @Qirel this is a school order :P i cant change this shit

Comment: *Facepalm* That's rather bad learning then in my opinion, but alright. After the conditions, dump `$class` to see what it contains, is it what you expect it to be?

Comment: string(0) "" string(8) "verleden" string(0) "" string(0) "" string(0) "" string(0) "" string(0) "" string(0) "" string(0) "" string(0) "" string(8) "verleden" string(0) "" string(0) "" string(8) "toekomst" string(8) "toekomst" its giving this back @Qirel

Comment: @Qirel i posted my code below

Comment: @Martini Put your code in the question (use the edit button), not in an answer.

Comment: @qirel sorry removing it and edit it give me a moment

Comment: @Qirel i editted how it looks like now

Answer (score 0):

Create two DateTime objects, and compare them in your conditions. DateTime objects can be compared to see which is the biggest (in date-time).

Preferably you would have one column `date` instead of separated into two different columns.

```
$now = new DateTime();
$date = new DateTime($row['datum']." ".$row['tijd']);

if ($now > $date) {
    $class = 'toekomst';
} elseif ($now == $date) {
    $class = 'vandaag';
} elseif ($now < $date) {
    $class = 'verleden';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if($row['datum'] > date("Y-m-d")) { $class = "toekomst"; }
if($row['datum'] == date("Y-m-d")) {
    if($row['tijd'] > date("H-i-s")) {$class = "vandaag"; }
else{ $class = "verleden"; }}
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your code such that others can learn from it.